# Try Catch w/Transaction and executing stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction, error-handling

I need to create an error-handling method for a couple of Stored Procedures.

Proc1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc1
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    EXEC Proc2

    INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2) values (1,GETDATE())
    
    --do something that causes error
    SELECT 1/0

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Proc2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc2
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    INSERT INTO tableB (col1,col2,col3) values (1,'John Doe',53)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

The reason I need nested `try/catch transactions` is that Proc2 can be called without proc1, but proc1 will always call proc2.

My question is, will that insert into `tableB` be rolled back?  If not, how can I make it roll back?

Comment: Please also consider having a look at the Q&As in [What happens if you cancel a job with multiple statements?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322575) for information on how transactions are handled implicitly and explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This is my stored procedure template: https://spaghettidba.com/2011/07/08/my-stored-procedure-code-template/

As the blog post says, it's based on avoiding nested transactions, which are illusory (it's basically just a transaction counter that gets increased).

It's quite an old blog posts, but there's not much I would change there. Maybe I would use `THROW` rather than `RAISERROR`, but the main concepts still stand.

Comment: +1 for `SET SACT_ABORT ON;`, a best practice for procs with explicit transactions.

Comment: I understand using the `@LocalTran` and `XACT_ABORT` ideas, and I'll add it, but you didn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: Also, as I stated in my questions.  I have to have nested try/catches, I can see a way to remove the nested transactions with your example.  But will the rollback in Proc1 rollback the insert from Proc2?

Comment: You don't need nested transactions for the reasons I explained and yes, rollbacks always roll back the whole transaction stack.

Answer (score 2):

> will that insert into tableB be rolled back?

Yes.  When called from `Proc1`, `Proc2`'s `BEGIN/COMMIT` creates a "nested transaction" so the `COMMIT` isn't a real commit, it just decrements [`@@trancount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

> The BEGIN TRANSACTION statement increments @@TRANCOUNT by 1. ROLLBACK TRANSACTION decrements @@TRANCOUNT to 0, except for ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint_name, which does not affect @@TRANCOUNT. COMMIT TRANSACTION or COMMIT WORK decrement @@TRANCOUNT by 1.